# Django how to get record id from ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been banging my head on this for weeks but I am determined to get ModelForm to work! When you process a POST with data received from a ModelForm, I understand that you need to get the original record from the database and then create a new form using that original record as the 'instance'. This is [documented in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) as follows:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Article
>>> from myapp.forms import ArticleForm

# Create a form instance from POST data.
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST)

# Save a new Article object from the form's data.
>>> new_article = f.save()

# Create a form to edit an existing Article, but use
# POST data to populate the form.
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
>>> f.save()
```

In this example they know that the pk of the record they are looking for is 1. BUT, how do you know the pk if you're reading data from request.POST, assuming that the POST is based on data you previously wrote to the screen? ModelForm doesn't store the pk. So, from where do you pick this up? Without it, how do you know which record to pull out of the DB (as in 'a' above)?

Thanks!

Ben

Comment: you can pass it to your view through the url for example. /articles/update/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in URLs to pass arguments to your view.

So if you have an url like :

```
url(r'^articles/update/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.update_article)
```

you could use in your view:

```
def update_article(request, article_id=None):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, @efkin. That worked! One small change is that I used the following regex: [0-9]*    This allows users to add new new articles by accessing the page without an article id.